# php include the page after "x" sec

Tags: php, html

There is a code given below

`header("refresh: 5; url=title.php");`

we all know that easy code. but i need a code that will include  a page after 5 second.

```
<?php include 'title.php':?>
```

this code will how after 5 second and the before link will be hide

Comment: `<?php sleep(5); include 'title.php';` will answer to question asked, but is probably not what you really want.

Comment: @eis: That's just mean :)

Comment: This wouldn't be done with server-side code.  You'd wait 5 seconds client-side and make an AJAX request to `title.php`, adding the result to the DOM.  Though it makes more sense to me to just include it right away but style the content to be hidden.  Then, after 5 seconds in client-side code, change the styling.

Comment: What do you mean include a page after 5 seconds? The page will already be on the client by then. You probably want to add code that will fetch content dynamically with AJAX. Unrelated suggestion, don't add "we all know" to your questions.

Comment: Why would you need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do something in the client-side, but you're trying to do it with server-side code. It would fit better with Javascript & jquery instead of PHP. You can get what you want with the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
        $("#whereToIncludeDiv").load("include.php");
        $("#link").addClass("hide");
      }, 5000);
    });
```

**Edit:**

Here is the full code:

index.php

```
<p>Some text</p>
<div id="includeDiv"></div>
<p>More text</p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
        $("#includeDiv").load("includethis.php");
        $("#link").addClass("hide");
    }, 5000);
});
```

includethis.php

```
<p>This is included text</p>
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is the full code as it is used on here

index.php (ofcourse, because of the .load, the snippet doesn't work if you click run snippet, but since I couldn't get it all in a codeblock for some weird reason, so this was the easiest solution)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Including PHP after x seconds</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div id="includeDiv"></div>
  <p>More text</p>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      (function() {
        $("#includeDiv").load("includethis.php");
        $("#link").addClass("hide");
      }, 5000);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

includethis.php

```
<p>This is included text</p>
```

**Edit 3:**

To hide one of the paragraphes, use the following:

```
<p id="hideme">Some text</p>
<div id="includeDiv"></div>
<p>More text</p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#includeDiv").load("includethis.php");
        $("#hideme").css("display", "none");
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Here is the code working live on my webhost: [http://jaspervanmerle.com/so/xseconds/index.php](http://jaspervanmerle.com/so/xseconds/index.php). Make sure to include jquery, I was using 1.12.0.

Comment: @JaspervanMerle: Did you forget a `setTimeout` somewhere in here?

Comment: In the link I just posted it works (atleast, for me it does), although it takes about 6 seconds instead of 5, which I can't explain but is probably related to jquery).

Comment: The some text and more text is just there to make clear where the included php file shows itself, it has no use in terms of functionality.

Comment: is it possible to do this??

Comment: @David, you were totally right, it somehow got removed.

Answer (score 3):

Don't "include the content after 5 seconds".  Adding delays in server-side code will only delay the rendering of the entire page, which probably isn't what you want.  Instead, include it right away, but style it to be hidden.  Something as simple as:

```
<div id="pageTitle" style="display:none">
    <?php include 'title.php'; ?>
</div>
```

Then in client-side code, wait 5 seconds and update the styling.  Maybe something like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('pageTitle').style.display = 'block';
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Include in the page invisible, then show it 5 seconds later.

```
 <div id="show-later" class="hidden">
     <?php include 'title.php':?> 
 </div>
 <script>
 setTimeout(function() {
     document.querySelector('#show-later').classList.remove('hidden');
 }, 5000);
 </script>
```